# url as parameters? in ASP.NET CORE

Tags: url, asp.net-core

Is there a way to read url as parameters?

for example url could be:

```
downloadSomething.com/data/json/something
```

And the method:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<Data> Data(string type, string otherParameter)
{
...
```

I know it's not a good practice.. I just want to know if is it possible.

Thx for help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you're asking here. The way routing works by default would allow this particular example.

```
[HttpGet("data/{type}/{otherParameter}")]
```

If you're talking about actually taking part of the path as a param, you can use the catch-all param, but it must be last param in the route (as it will obviously swallow everything).

```
[HttpGet("data/{**stuff}")]
```

That would then set the param `stuff` with the full path: `json/something`.